# Why does cycles my rendering look like this?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

Why does cycles rendering look like this ?

[image]

I don t want it spherical, and has the little dots.

Comment: and 2 of the windows have opaque finish even though I set the same material for all of them ...

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a descriptive title that summarizes the content of the question, avoid any extraneous text that aren't strictly necessary to answer the question,

Comment: ok ,sorry I will do next .